# Android/Java-Why are these not used?

Tags: java, android, arrays, methods, increment

I am currently working on a simple quiz app on android using android studio and genymotion. the app has 10 questions in total, the other 8 of which I will add later. Most of the code seems fine to me. However, there are a couple of things I can't get my head around, some of the methods say that they aren't used no matter what I try and the same with the variable incorrectAnswers. basically, I want the quiz to ask 10 questions, changing the screen after the radio buttons have been hit and then ending after question 10 telling the user their score.

Does anyone know how to resolve this as I am at my wits end? Have I made any other mistakes that need correcting that I have not noticed?

Thanks.

This is the code with the queries highlighted with **:

```
package com.quiz.quizsample.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //Called when the activity is first created

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
        initialise();
    }




    private int currentQuestion;
    private  String [] questions;
    private  String [] answerA;
    private  String [] answerB;
    private  String [] answerC;
    private  String [] answerD;
    private  String [] correctAnswer;


    Button answerButton;
    TextView questionView;
    TextView answerView;
    TextView resultView;
    EditText answerText;
    RadioButton A;
    RadioButton B;
    RadioButton C;
    RadioButton D;
    Button end;


    public void initialise()
    {
        questions = new String[]{"Which year did the Isle of Wight festival begin?","Why"};
        answerA = new String[] {"A","1999"};
        answerB = new String[] {"n","k"};
        answerC = new String[] {"n","k"};
        answerD = new String[] {"n","k"};
        correctAnswer = new String[] {"n","k"};


        currentQuestion = 0;
        answerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);

        questionView = (TextView)
        findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonA);
        B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonB);
        C = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonC);
        D = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonD);
        answerView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
        answerText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);

    }

        public void **showQuestion()**
    {
        currentQuestion=0;
        if(currentQuestion<10)

        currentQuestion++;
            questionView.setText(currentQuestion+1);
            A.setText(answerA[currentQuestion+1]);
            B.setText(answerB[currentQuestion+1]);
            C.setText(answerC[currentQuestion+1]);
            D.setText(answerD[currentQuestion+1]);





        answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer();
            }
        });


        questionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton **answer** = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                showQuestion();
            }
        });

    }//This method increments currentQuestion index, checks if it equal to the size of the array and rest if necessary



    public void **getCountQuestion**()
    {
        int countQuestion=0;
        if(countQuestion<10)
            countQuestion++;
            questionView.setText(questions[countQuestion]);`enter code here`




        answerView.setText("");
        answerText.setText("");
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
    {
        return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer[currentQuestion]));
    }



    public void checkAnswer()
    {
        String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
        if(isCorrect(answer))
            answerView.setText("You're right!");
        else
            answerView.setText("Sorry, the correct answer is " +correctAnswer[currentQuestion]);

    }

    public void **getResult**()
    {

        int numberCorrectAnswers = 0;
        int **IncorrectAnswers** = 0;
        **IncorrectAnswers** =10 - numberCorrectAnswers;
        numberCorrectAnswers = new int[**correctAnswer**];
        numberCorrectAnswers++;


        {

    if (numberCorrectAnswers >6)

        resultView.setText("Well done, you passed the quiz.");

    }//end if

    {
        if (numberCorrectAnswers <=7)



            resultView.setText("Sorry, you have failed the quiz. Please try again soon.");

    }//end if

    {

    { if (numberCorrectAnswers >=7)

        resultView.setText(" You are a festival expert!");

    else if (numberCorrectAnswers <2 )

        resultView.setText("You must think that music begins and ends with Oasis. Please try harder next time!");

    else if (numberCorrectAnswers <4)

        resultView.setText ("You need to get out more to festivals!");

    else
        resultView.setText("Not bad for a first try");
    }
}
}
}//class
```

Comment: They are not used, because you don't use them anywhere.  I would delete them because if you needed them anywhere you would have used them, I assume.

Comment: I am going to delete incorrectAnswers as I presume the score can be generated on the back of correct answers alone. How do I use those methods then? Have you got any sample code to give me an idea? Thanks.

Comment: It's your code, and if you don't know when they need to be called, no-one does.  I would delete them and then add code to do what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

YOu declare incorrectAnswers, you assign incorrectAnswers. But then you do nothing with it. If it merely holds a value, but nothing else cares, the Java compiler will do exactly what it should - tell you that its not used and will likely not bother to generate code for it.

Comment: are there any other mistakes besides the ones that I have mentioned that may stop it from running?

Comment: @user3604547 - "are there any other mistakes" -- probably, but this is not a website for code reviews.